# How to call the __init__ method of the mothe class?

Tags: python

I have the following error:
`Error Traceback (most recent call last): line 25,line 14,line 3 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Teamname'`

Here is my python code:

```py
    class Team:
        def __init__(self,Name = "Name",Origin= "india"):
            self.Teamname = Name
            self.Teamorigin= Origin

        def DefTeamname(self,Name):
            self.Teamname = Name
        def defTeamorigin(self,Origin):
            self.Teamorigin = Origin


    class Player(Team):
        def __init__(self,Pname,Ppoints,Tname,Torigin):
            Team.__init__(Tname,Torigin)
            self.Playername = Pname
            self.Playerpoints = Ppoints

        def Scoredpoint(self):
            self.Playerpoints += 1

        def __str__(self):
            return self.Playername + "has scored" + str(self.Playerpoints) + "points"

    Player1 = Player('Sid',0,'Gokulam','Kochi')
    print(Player1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a question? What have you tried? What are you hoping to find?

Comment: A Player is certainly not *a specific kind of* Team, so having `Player` inherit from `Team` is utterly inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class Player(Team):
    def __init__(self,Pname,Ppoints,Tname,Torigin):
        super().__init__(Tname,Torigin)
        ...
```

You cannot call `__init__` yourself on the class, you need to call on the instance by using `super()` notation, else the `self` parameter will not be bound correctly

Comment: Thank you so much editing that line to "Team.__init__(self,Tname,Torigin)" also worked

Answer (score 2):

Your error is being thrown because the first argument to `__init__` is being interpreted as `self`, and `__init__` is therefore trying to mutate it.  It only works at all because you use keyword arguments, so `Origin` is just falling back to the default.

Note for completeness that you *can* call the method directly on the target class (or any other class for that matter), but that `self` is not bound and you lose the advantage of `super()` always pointing to the parent in the MRO.  This works:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._b = b
        A.__init__(self, a)

b = B(6, 7)
assert b._a == 6
```

Incidentally this shows that `__init__` is just a function which takes a muteable first arg (`self` by convention) and mutates that arg.

You really should use `super()` however. What happens if I redefine A?:

```py
class newA:
    def __init__(self):
        self._other = True

class A(newA):
    ...
```

If you have used `super()` all the way through, everything will work fine:

```py
class NewA:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class A(NewA):
    def __init__(self, a=None, **kwargs):
        self._a = a
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Note the use of keyword arguments to pass up the chain without worrying about the semantics of every class's init.

### Further Reading

- [Python's super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)
- [Python's super considered harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) for warnings about how things can go wrong if you *don't* keep your semantics compatible.